# Problema con ruta en hosting con server en nodejs

Tags: nodejs, express

Estimada comunidad muy buenas con todos, tengo un problema del cual no puedo salir y espero de todo corazon su ayuda; sucede que en mi dominio he creado un server en nodejs del cual estoy generando las rutas para su consulta respectiva

> http://andenesdelahera.com/serverexp/

en mi server local cuando ejecuto las peticiones get y post en las siguiente direcciones:

- http://localhost:3000/serverexp/ (get y post)
- http://localhost:3000/serverexp/prueba (post)

me da una respuesta correcta que recibe la data, pero cuando ingreso a mi dominio de la misma manera, para hacer la prueba ya sea con thunderbird o postman en los 2 links (adjunto imagen):

- http://andenesdelahera.com/serverexp/ (get y post) me da respuesta correcta
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- http://andenesdelahera.com/serverexp/prueba (post) me manda error 404 de que no encuentra el recurso
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto codigo de mi app server, por favor en que me estoy equivocando agradezco nuevamente su ayuda

Saludos.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.text());

app.get('/serverexp', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url);
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.post('/serverexp', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('Hello World! ahora')
})

app.post('/serverexp/prueba', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('Hello World! probando')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si agregas un `all(*)` al final? `app.all('*', (req, res) => {res.status(404).send('Not found path: ' + req.path + 'route: ' + req.route);}`